# How can I use JeringTech/Javascript.NodeJS to invoke node to run js code inside a .NET API?

Tags: c#, node.js, asp.net, .net

I want to be able to execute javascript code in my back-end .NET API, so I tried following [these steps](https://github.com/JeringTech/Javascript.NodeJS/tree/master#using-the-static-api) and I created a .NET API as follows:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Jering.Javascript.NodeJS;
using System.Net;

namespace NodeJSTestAPI.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("testNodeJS/")]
    public class TestNodeJSController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<TestNodeJSController> _logger;

        public TestNodeJSController( ILogger<TestNodeJSController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet("invokeTest/")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(object[]), 200)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> InvokeTest(string testString)
        {
            Result? result = await StaticNodeJSService.InvokeFromStringAsync<Result>("module.exports = (callback, message) => callback(null, message);", args: new[] { "success" });

            return Content(result.Message, "application/json");
        }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public string? Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I would expect that once I request `GET API_URL/testNodeJS/invokeTest/` from postman it would run the javascript code specified, however I am getting a 500 error with the exception below:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No such host is known.
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11001): No such host is known.
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Jering.Javascript.NodeJS.HttpNodeJSService.TryInvokeAsync[T](InvocationRequest invocationRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Jering.Javascript.NodeJS.OutOfProcessNodeJSService.TryInvokeCoreAsync[T](InvocationRequest invocationRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Jering.Javascript.NodeJS.OutOfProcessNodeJSService.InvokeFromStringAsync[T](String moduleString, String newCacheIdentifier, String exportName, Object[] args, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at NodeJSTestAPI.Controllers.TestNodeJSController.InvokeTest(String testString) in C:\Users\nunebr\Documents\git-workspace\supply-chain-planning-tool\planning-apps-back-end\NodeJSTestAPI\Controllers\TestNodeJSController.cs:line 28
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Host: localhost:44393
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.33.0
Postman-Token: a1a9a285-d633-41dd-a6d7-e02c04d8024e
MS-ASPNETCORE-TOKEN: b0d6204e-859a-41b1-90e8-0b350697c062
X-Original-Proto: http
X-Original-For: 127.0.0.1:55630
```

Does anyone know what I might be missing on this issue?

On a separate note, I used to have this same code running fine in a different laptop, however since I needed to change laptop, I can't make it work again, so not sure if it could be some network configuration issue blocking my .NET API to access the invoked NodeJS.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This error "No such host is known" suggests that the Host name/IpAddress is incorrect.  So either it is wrong/missing in your service (we can't see this code & config so can't comment), or the Server is not running, or it can't be accessed for some reason (e.g. firewall problem).  So you need to look into these issues to see which one it is.  Have you tried calling you JS backend from Postman directly?

Comment: There is no JS backend, the only backend is in .net and .net is supposed to be able to execute js code (I believe it will try to spin up a NodeJS server behind the scenes but not 100% sure) so I don't have a way of calling JS backend directly.

Comment: this smells like IPv6 shenanigans... long shot, but if you can try disabling IPv6 on the OS level, things might work again.

Comment: might also be worth reporting this to Jering, if you have a repro.

Comment: thanks for the tips @BrunoMedeiros unfortunately even after disabling ipv6 on OS level as well as individually disabling it in each network adapter the issue still remains... I've also reported the issue in the repository github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had previously set http_proxy and https_proxy pointing to my corporate proxy address and this was causing all http requests from .NET to be redirected to the proxy address and causing the error "No such host is known", after removing those 2 environment variables, the code is working as expected connecting to the node server.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved by reading the messages that are logged. Logging is enabled through dependency injection.

Here is an example of a simple console application under .net 7.0

```cs
using Jering.Javascript.NodeJS;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace ConsoleApp;

internal class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string javascriptModule = @"
module.exports = (callback, x, y) => { // Module must export a function that takes a callback as its first parameter
    var result = x + y; // Your javascript logic
    callback(null /* If an error occurred, provide an error object or message */, result); // Call the callback when you're done.
}";
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services
            .AddNodeJS()
            .AddLogging(opt =>
            {
                opt.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace)
                   .AddSimpleConsole();
            });
        StaticNodeJSService.SetServices(services);

        var result = await StaticNodeJSService.InvokeFromStringAsync<int>(javascriptModule, args: new object[] { 3, 5 });

        Console.WriteLine($"Complete with result {result}");
    }
}
```

To make this work, we need to add two more nuget packages.

```
dotnet add ConsoleApp package Jering.Javascript.NodeJS --version 7.0.0.0
dotnet add ConsoleApp package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console --version 7.0.0
```

If there are problems deciphering the output, you can attach the console output to the question

Comment: I've got a similar advice from the issue I raised with JeringTech [here](https://github.com/JeringTech/Javascript.NodeJS/issues/181) however the logs show me that it might be my corporate proxy blocking me from connecting to node, the only problem is that proxy only blocks .NET connecting to node server in localhost, if I run an angular app and a .NET API, they can connect to each other just fine

Comment: @BrunoPortugal Alternatively, you can try to configure the server to start on static 5000 port via NodeJSProcessOptions

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will solve the full issue, but you should start by looking into your endpoint configuration.
Currently, your code is expecting a `string testString` as a parameter for your `GET` method, but you're not providing one in your definition.
Try changing your code to:

```
[HttpGet("invokeTest/{testString}")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(object[]), 200)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> InvokeTest(string testString)
        {
            Result? result = await StaticNodeJSService.InvokeFromStringAsync<Result>("module.exports = (callback, message) => callback(null, message);", args: new[] { "success" });

            return Content(result.Message, "application/json");
        }
```

Note that we're adding `{testString}` to your `[HttpGet("invokeTest/")]` endpoint definition in order to allow your function to actually pick that value up.